# Multilingual implementation in MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, multilingual

How can I create a MVC3 Razor Label which shows the label text in selected culture(Language)?

I am having get&set culture function and a dropdown list to select the language. I also have a resource file in /Content/Resource folder.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966680/asp-net-mvc-input-model-validation-multi-language/6750261#6750261 in particular with the localised display name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a good article which explain how to implement Multilingual in MVC 3 Razor project.

Find the article from the URL

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/BilingualMvc3Part1.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Be sure to check out part 2 of his article where he handles a SEO friendly way.