# How should laying out data sent to view in regard to localized texts be approached in asp .net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, localization, design-patterns

Let's say I want to show a fieldset that contains a form and a button.

There will be some textboxes for I/O values and some labels for:

1. the fieldset title (not related to values)
2. textboxes (labels and validations)
3. the submit button (not related to values)

The labels will be provided from a database based on localization.

For case 2 I would like to use the mechanisms for which mvc already has support (DataAnnotations attributes) so I have found the following 2 solutions:

- write a database resource-provider to use with DataAnnotations attributes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx#exaspnet20rpm_topic4)
- extend DataAnnotations attributes to use my database context and retrieve the localized text ([asp.net mvc input / model validation multi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966680/asp-net-mvc-input-model-validation-multi-language))

A view model example would be something like this:

```
Model
{
    fieldset title localized label

    [textbox localized display label]
    [textbox localized validation label]
    textbox value

    button localized label
}
```

While the labels for case 2 are specified as meta-data for the view model values, what would be an elegant and consistent way for specifying localized texts from a database for case 1 and 3 considering a view with a big content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution, although overkill, would be to have an empty model member with a display attribute for each localized label and to use a custom helper<sup>[1]</sup> to retrieve the plain text.

<sub>[1]: [Get DisplayName Attribute without using LabelFor Helper in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885796/get-displayname-attribute-without-using-labelfor-helper-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=active#tab-top)</sub>